Can anyone identify the materials and technique used in this stone wall construction?
I have a section of an exposed stone wall that I'm curious about. The wall appears to be made of roughly cut stones of varying shades, held together by a grey mortar-like material. The texture and finish seem a bit rustic, and I wonder if this might be a traditional method or a modern interpretation.
I am not an expert, but I am a hobbyist with some experience in scagliola. I've made some simple pieces of art, and now I want to create something like this.
I do not have any experience in architecture, so please explain things considering this. Also, I do not want to build a wall or anything like that: I am only investigating because I want to incorporate such techniques in my art.
Are there any clues from the texture, arrangement, or color of the materials that indicate a specific construction technique or period? I’ve attached close-up images for reference.
Thank you in advance for any insights!




"The wall appears to be made of roughly cut stones of varying shades, held together by a grey mortar-like material." It seems to me it's a regular and commonplace (perhaps depending on your global location) brick wall, using mortar and bricks that happen to be yellow (see e.g. here).

What kind of art are you thinking of making? The only logical medium to incorporate this, apart from architecture, would be sculpture.

These are yellow-coloured bricks (e.g. London stock bricks, Cream City bricks, or perhaps even Frisian tiles).
Yellow bricks contain more lime, but the final look is also influenced by firing temperature and the kiln atmosphere (see here).
The bricks are held together by a mortar: given the homogeneity of the mortar it seems modern, giving the impression it was made using the common Portland cement mortar or an equivalent.
The mortar joints are concave and seemingly in good condition.
The bulk of the parts of the wall in the photos might be covered in repairs, so it's hard to judge the age of the wall proper based on these photos, and especially without any details on the location and environment, but it seems like a relatively new wall.
